# Alerts não são disparados na página

Tags: php, javascript

Bom dia, estou tentando chama rum **alert** usando `<script>` no PHP, mas ele não carrega.

```
  if(isset($_POST['comprar'])) {
    //Seta variaveis para sessions a serem utilizadas


//Verifica se todos os requesitos foram POSTADOS
if(!$_POST['ad']) {
die ("<script>alert('Erro')</script>"); <<Script não aparece
}else{
$cc = $_POST['ad'];

}




//Procura o preço do lote no Banco de Dados
$procuraPreco = mysqli_query($connect, "SELECT PRECO FROM materiais WHERE ad='$cc'"); 
$retornaPreco = mysqli_fetch_all($procuraPreco,MYSQLI_ASSOC);
$preco = $retornaPreco[0]['PRECO'];

//Verifica se possui saldo suficiente
if($saldo < $preco) {
die('<script>alert("Pedido recusado. Razão: Saldo insuficiente"); </script>'); <<Script não aparece 

}

/*$insereAdm = mysqli_query($connect, "INSERT INTO compras (comprador,seis_primeiro,bandeira,bin,quantidade,preco,vendedor,id) VALUES ('$user','$seis','$bandeira','$bin','$qntd','$preco','$vendedor','$id')");*/
$sub = $saldo - $preco;
$subtraiSaldo = mysqli_query($connect, "UPDATE usuarios SET saldo='$sub' WHERE usuario='$user'");

$deletaLote = mysqli_query($connect,"DELETE FROM materiais2 WHERE cc='$cc'");
   die('<script>alert("Compra realizada");</script>'); << Script não aparece

}
```

Nenhum dos ALERTS aparecem na página, apenas no Response da página do F12
Nota: O PHP está acima do HTML

Answer (score 1):

Sua chamada deveria estar assim:

```
die("<script type="text/javascript">alert('Erro')</script>");
```

Declarando qual o tipo do script que você está chamando.